# Create a windows installer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Information regarding the walkthrough of a Windows installer creation from a Visual Studio solution ( which contains a dll and a app project), are really limited through the internet.

How can we do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293568.aspx as builtin example, or http://wix.codeplex.com/ as a solid alternative. But you will need to do some reading in both cases

Comment: @Najzero Thank you, I have already dealt with the link you are providing me. It has just created an MSM file in the release but I cannot make it work?

Comment: Merge modules are like static linked LIB files in C/C++.  They serve as a reusable library but cannot be installed by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup development is, well, development.  You don't just read one or two blogs and all of a sudden know how to do everything you need to do.

I suggest checking out WiX and reading:

[WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](http://www.packtpub.com/wix-developers-guide-windows-installer-xml/book)

I wrote an opensource tool for WiX called [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/) and you can use it to assist in authoring WiX installers.  A silent video showing it's use to create an MSI for a Windows Service can be found [here](http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. Example can be found here.
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started

Installsheild is another one,but it is not opensource